# Accessory Widget Rectangular with Rounded Corners, Highlighted Background

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit, lockscreenwidget

My iOS accessory widget (a.k.a. iOS 16 "lockscreen" widget) supports both the `.accessoryRectangular` and `.accessoryCircular` families.

But since I want a "pill" shape for my rectangular widget (instead of the default sharp corners), I came up with this code for my background view:

```
private var backgroundView: some View {
  return GeometryReader { geometry in
    AccessoryWidgetBackground()
      .cornerRadius(geometry.size.height / 2.0)
  }  
}
```

and thus, my widgets' backgrounds for both families look like this:

[image]

**So far, so good.**

**However**, when I tap on the rectangular widget, the newly revealed clear background around the rounded corners gets "highlighted" in a semi-opaque white color, like this:

[image]

Note that **this does not happen with the circular widget**, even though it is using the same geometry reader + rounded corner code as the rectangular one.

My hunch is that this difference is due to how Apple internally implements the background view for each widget family; because they expect the background to seamlessly fill its bounds in the rectangular case, maybe they do something different with the background view's internals...

**Has anyone run into a similar issue, and figured out a workaround?**

Comment: Having the same exact problem. I ended up just using a clip shape: `.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))`